# Range between values, percentage to value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

So I have 2 values:

min: -57
max: 80

I wanna know the value of for example 60%

Sorry if this is simple question but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The number that is $x\%$ of the way between the numbers $a$ and $b$ (assuming that $a<b$) is
$$a+\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)(b-a)$$
Why? Because $b-a$ is the distance between the numbers $a$ and $b$,  so we "start" at the lower number $a$ and "go" $x\%$ (in other words $\frac{x}{100}$) of the total distance to $b$.

So for example, the number that is $60\%$ of the way between $-57$ and $80$ is
$$\begin{align*}
&\hphantom{=}-57+\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)(80-(-57))\\\\
&=-57+\left(\frac{60}{100}\right)(137)\\\\
&=-57+\frac{8220}{100}\\\\
&=-57+82.2\\\\
&=25.2
\end{align*}$$